# Usage of ScriptInjector in GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I want to use javascript library in java source code. I read sth about it and I read, that I should use `ScriptInjector`. This class has 2 inner classes: `ScriptInjector.FromString` and `ScriptInjector.FromUrl`. I want to load javascript library from local file, so I should use from string. How to do it?

```
ScriptInjector.fromString("myLibrary.js");
```

does not work. Where to add library?

Comment: I tried this: http://simon.pamies.de/archives/194 , but this is not working.

Answer (score 6):

1) `fromUrl` - creates `script` tag with specified **src** attribute and appends it to the page. E.g.

```
ScriptInjector.fromUrl("http://example.com/my-script.js").inject();
```

will simply produce:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/my-script.js" />
```

You can host your files on the web site and inject each of them on demand

2) `fromString` - creates `script` tag with specified **body** of the script, so:
ScriptInjector.fromString("alert('Injected!')").inject();
will give

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('Injected!')
</script>
```

In this case JS code is a part of your compiled GWT code and browser doesn't require to load it with separate request. I think it is possible to include native JS file into compiled output with `TextResource`. So you need following:

Define resources

```
public interface JsResources extends ClientBundle {
final JsResources INSTANCE = GWT.create(JsResources.class);
@Source("first.js")
TextResource firstScript();
@Source("second.js")
TextResource secondScript();
}
```

Inject required script

```
ScriptInjector.fromString(JsResources.INSTANCE.firstScript().getText()).inject();
```

Comment: "I think it is possible to include native JS file into compiled output with TextResource." I can cofirm that: I just managed to rewrite my own code the way you proposed above, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

To use `.fromString()` you'd have to load the JS into a String and pass that.

If you need to load the script using the `.fromUrl()` you'll have to put it somewhere "Internet" accessible, since the `inject()` ends up in

```
private static native void nativeSetSrc(JavaScriptObject element, String url) /*-{
  element.src = url;
}-*/;
```

(See it [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.java?r=10407))

So: Extract or otherwise expose the script to your webserver.

Cheers,

Comment: I wrote down: ScriptInjector.fromUrl(file://myLibrary.js).inject(); Library is stil not injected, because elements from this library cannot be accessed.

Comment: Three slashes (the hostname may go between number 2 and 3). The path (after 3rd slash) has to be correct. Remember enclosing quotes.

Comment: The same problem. I have file in the same package as class, which loads this file.

Comment: I dug around a bit, and ended up editing the answer.

Comment: So file can be loaded only using a method fromString() ? `src` means file in website?

Comment: I want to hvae two separate files, not integrate this all into one file. Can I do it with `fromString()` method?